# Unwanted left margin in chemfig schemes

Tags: chemfig

I am writing some reactions in a `chemfig` scheme, but the spacing between the molecules is uneven. Turning on the debug mode (with `\schemedebug{true}`) shows that, for every molecule in the scheme, the bounding box sticks to the molecule on every side except the left side, where there is a margin.

In this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/354474/137146), the molecules are evenly spaced, so I assume there is no such margin.

[image: Result from the answer]

MWE from that answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document} 
\schemestart 
\chemleft[\subscheme{\chemfig[][scale=.7]{-[:-30]=^[:30]-[2]=^[: 150]-[:-150]=^[6]}\arrow{<->} \chemfig[][scale=.7]{=^[:-30]-[:30]=^[2]-[: 150]=^[:-150]-[6]}}\chemright] 
\schemestop 
\end{document}
```

However, if I use the same MWE and compile it, I don't get the same result: there is a margin on the left.

[image: Result on my computer]

With debug mode on:

[image]

How can I remove this?

My version of `chemfig` is the latest one (v1.3, 2018-03-08).

Comment: I can confirm that the space appears with 1.3 but not with 1.2e, so might be worth informing the package author of this, by making a bug report at https://framagit.org/unbonpetit/chemfig/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: The author of the chemfig will soon publish a fixed version 1.31. In the meantime, he reported a workaround for this bug:

https://framagit.org/unbonpetit/chemfig/issues/1

In case the link does not work, you have to copy this piece of code to the preamble in your file (after the `\usepackage{chemfig}`):

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\CF@ifnextchar#1#2#3{%
    \let\CF@ifnextchar@tok=#1% <- espace indésirable, bugfix dans 1.31
    \def\CF@ifnextchar@codetrue{#2}%
    \def\CF@ifnextchar@codefalse{#3}%
    \futurelet\CF@temptok\CF@ifnextchar@i}
\makeatother
```

---

EDIT: I copy/pasted your code and tried it with chemfig 1.2e and also with the latest v1.3 and the result is without the left margin in the 1.2e and with the margin in v1.3. So there is definitely a bug in the new version.

Version 1.2e:

[image]

Version 1.3:

[image]

Comment: Sure about that? I *do* get the space with 1.3, but not with 1.2e.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You are absolutely right. Thanks for double-checking. The version v1.3 was not installed correctly and I did not notice it.