# \chemleft bracket too far from molecule

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig

I am trying to draw a reaction scheme in chemfig, but the chemleft bracket is too far away from the actual molecule and I do not know why. My code looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\setchemfig{cram width=3pt}
\schemestart
\subscheme{
\chemleft[
    \chemfig{@{F}\Lewis{0:2:4:6:,F}}
\chemright]}
\+
\chemfig{F-@{B}{\phantom{B}}(-[2,0,,,draw=none]{})(<[:-20]F)<:[:20]F}
\arrow{->}
\chemleft[
    \chemfig{\chembelow[0.5pt]{F}{\scriptstyle\hspace{4.5mm}\oplus}-[@{cb}:-90,0.8]\chemabove[0.5pt]{B}{\scriptstyle\hspace{4.5mm}\ominus}(<:[:-40,0.8]F)(<[:-70,0.8]F)-[:-140]F}
\chemright]
\schemestop
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
\begin{scope}[overlay,shift={(B)}]
\draw[-] (-0.1,0.2) ..controls +(120:1) and +(60:1) .. (0.1,0.2);
\draw[-,fill=black!10] (-0.1,-0.2) ..controls +(-120:1) and +(-60:1) .. 
+(0.2,0);
\end{scope}
\node[fill=white,inner sep=0.1pt] at (B){{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont
B
}};
\draw[-latex,shorten <=2pt] (F) ..controls +(90:1.7cm)and+(90:1cm)..
([yshift=9pt]B.north);
\draw[-latex,densely dashed] (cb) arc (270:180:0.7 and 1) node[above=0.15cm,align=center] {\scriptsize coordinate \scriptsize covalent\\ \scriptsize bond};
}
\chemmove{\node[xshift=5pt] at (c2.north east) {$-$};}
\chemmove{\node[xshift=5pt] at (c3.north east) {$-$};}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output which illustrates my problem
[image]
As you can see, the left [ (`chemleft[`) braces are placed at some distance from the actual molecule. How do I fix this?

Comment: On my updated TeXLive2018 distribution, I do not get the gaps when I compile with either `pdflatex` or `lualatex`. If I compile with `xelatex`, I do not get the gaps either, however the output is screwed up in many other ways,

Comment: I'm using miktex 2.9 and texworks and the issue comes with both `pdflatex` and `luatex`. What do you mean by the output is screwed up in many other ways? Often you have to compile it two or three times for it to work properly?

Comment: I did compile 3 times with `xelatex` and the result is completely off. This is not your fault, but there are several occasions in which `xelatex` "misbehaves". However, I cannot reproduce the gaps. I also have no idea what miktex does, but I think there should be a way to update the packages.

Comment: Are you suggesting that updating my chemfig package may resolve the issue?

Comment: I honestly don't know but sometimes that works, yes. But please don't blame me if it fails.

Comment: ofc not, out of curiousity would a negative horizontal spacing resolve the issue?

Comment: Hard to tell, probably yes, but as soon as you do an update or fix the fundamental problem this will screw up the result. That is, if you compile the file later, you may have real problems.

Comment: Updating did not resolve the issue, I will try using negative hspace

Comment: negative `hspace` works and I guess is a temporary solution, strange. I couldn't find any other similar questions discussing the same problem

Comment: I think this question is duplicate/related to
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424040/unwanted-left-margin-in-chemfig-schemes/